# Where does a thread end?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently learning c# and would like to know where it ends, is it at the `t.Start` or does is continue from there or should I call a other method from the threadMethod? Thanks in advance.

```
private void startThread()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadMethod));
    t.Start();
}

private void threadMethod()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The new thread will run `threadMethod` and then be terminated. Meanwhile and afterwards as well, your main thread runs as usual.

Comment: ThreadStart is not needed in newer .NET versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread stops when its method has finished or fails, in your case threadMethod().

Comment: Is there anyway to continue the code in the main thread, like from where the thread started?

Comment: Or if the thread is aborted, or if an exception is thrown from that method, or the process is terminated for some reason, or probably some other exceptional case that I haven't considered.

Comment: The Thread.Join method as suggested by Servy or just use the backgroundworker class, which has events that trigger when the thread has stopped etc and can really ease the process of working with threads.

Comment: @Royboy510 You can use `Thread.Join` to have the calling thread wait for the spawned thread to finish before continuing on.  In this particular case though it would defeat the purpose of starting the new thread.

Answer (score 3):

Thread *normally* ends when `threadMethod` stops its execution.

Answer (score 0):

the thread ends when the threadMethod ends. Notice that by executing threadMethod asynchronously startThread() is going to finish before the threadMethod().

it is probably a good idea to study the multi-threading concept first before going forward with c# ( or at least doing both together ) it will things way easier and faster for you to get to learn

good luck

Comment: startThread *may* finish before `threadMethod`.  You have no idea which, so you need to be able to handle both cases.

Comment: I'm saying given the example he gaves us where starting the new thread us THE last instruction he does in startThread

Comment: Yep, so am I.  You have no idea how the threads will be scheduled.  It could just so happen that the main thread's timeslice will end just after it spawns the new thread (and before it returns) and that the new thread will run next, possibly finishing before the next time the main thread is scheduled again.  It's *unlikely* with the code provided, but still possible.  With certain modifications you could make either option *more likely*, or you could use locking to ensure some desired ordering.